# Mysql multidelete from more identical database, with different name

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is my situation.
I have on same server more identical mysql database, each with different names.
Example db_01,db_02,db_03 and so on...
I wanto to delete, based on condition, some records from one table(house) of each db, in single query. 
The house table is identical in structure for each DB, but data are different.
The data included within each house table are inserted independently by different people. So same structure but different data.
I try this:

```
DELETE db_01.house.* , db_02.house.*  FROM db_01.house , db_02.house 
WHERE  
db_01.house.data_reminder < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
AND 
db_02.house.data_reminder < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
```

This query is executed without error, but the WHERE condition obviously does not work well, because putting the AND, if the condition is not checked on one table, the query does not do anything. If i  use the OR it delete in all tables.
In other words, I need  that any condition written for each table is independent of the other.

I think that i can't use JOIN because the table are identical and there is not JOIN condition from this table.

How can I do?
Thanks in advance.